# How does Google track impressions for SEO: does it count times where it is in the results, but not visible?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, impressions, ctr

I am quite aware about what SEO impressions are: i.e. number of times your site result are listed in the Google search results. But are the impressions are counted if they are visible at least once in user's viewport or just if Google has thrown them to the user in its search list?

For example assume a result that is at rank 7-10 which is not even in user's viewport. User clicks on result 1 and has not even viewed my result. In this case, does Google track this as impression?

Is this data available in webmaster report, so that we can get a better estimate of our CTR?

Something like :

> Total Impressions : 10000
>   Impressions Viewed (some other meaningful name) :  5000
>   Clicks : 500
>
> CTR overall : 5%
>   CTR/viewed results : 10%

This data could be really helpful and provide better insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Google, "Impressions - How many links to your site a user saw on Google search results, even if the link was not scrolled into view. However, if a user views only page 1 and the link is on page 2, the impression is not counted." ([source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en))

Comment: Well answered @Jurga , it would be great if you can add light on possibility of getting the visible impression count as well

Comment: There was a very interesting study published on Moz showing the scrolling behaviour differences on mobile and desktop [source] (https://moz.com/blog/eye-tracking-2016-how-searchers-interact-mobile-serps-desktop) - hope it helps with rough estimations.